# editar un input type file "imagen" en codeigniter

Tags: php, imagen, upload

estoy haciendo una edición de un formulario logro cargar la imagen por defecto del path de imágenes en la vista, al momento de guardar los cambios me sale una alerta como si no hubiese ninguna imagen cargada en la vista..
esta advertencia solo me sale si es que no modifico(subo) otra imagen.
Este es mi código en view.php

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="card">                                    
<label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Foto</label>
<label for="input-file-now-custom-3">OJO Solo archivos png</label>                                        
<input type="file" id="input-file-now-custom-3" class="dropify" name="foto_org" data-allowed-file-extensions="png" data-default-file="<?php echo base_url(); ?><?php echo $datos->url; ?>/<?php echo $datos->imagen ?>" required/>                                                                         
</div>
</div>
```

el formulario

[image: esa la captura del formulario]

Comment: si te retiras el required de "<input type="file..." se soluciona tu problema, por ende deberías hacer la validación de otra forma.

Comment: a lo que veo con java script lo tendre que validar